# Reverse sort for question feeds and search

Tags: feature-request, sorting, search

Is it possible to allow users to select the direction sorting is applied in for `/questions` and `/search`? Something like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest?direction=desc`. In terms of UI, this could be toggled by clicking on the sort tab:

[image]

Right now you have to scroll to the bottom of the page and click the last entry in the pager to get the oldest questions or the lowest voted ones etc.

This isn't a massive inconvenience, but putting in this feature shouldn't be too difficult (I assume) and it would be useful.

Comment: Yes please. The last page workaround is actually impossible when your search turns up more than 5k results.