# Reverse chronological order with user:me?

Tags: support, android-app

In [Viewing all my questions from Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271428/297638), I received the answer that I can view my posts in reverse chronological order by typing *user:me* at the top in the search box for an SE site. BUT the results are not in reverse chronological order as I requested.

How do I get this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could it be that you see in the list is the last active date of the Q/A pair while the list in indeed ordered on the creationdate of your posts? So it is an presentation issue?

Comment: I assume this is the android app. If this is incorrect please remove the tag.

Comment: Yes it could be, but still, the order is chronological and not reverse chronological. And yes, I am using the Android app. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the sort direction is not possible, even in the desktop site ([existing feature request asking to add it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155394/reverse-sort-for-question-feeds-and-search)), so obviously it won't be part of the app which gives only very basic access. It's meant for reading existing posts and writing new posts, anything else is just a bonus.

Comment: I hope it gets implementeff. If the list is long, it is a bit of a pain to scroll through. Plus, it is always more likely one would want to access recent posts first, rather than old posts.

Comment: Everything *is* shown with most recent first isn't it??